# Cancel FieldUpdater on GWT dataGrid if same value

Tags: gwt, datagrid, auto-update

I'm new to `GWT`. I integrated a dataGrid with many "`EditTextCell`" columns. Every column has a "`FieldUpdater`" which updates the value in the database.

My problem is that every time I go into any cell (field), but **do not perform any operation** (I keep the same value in the field), the "`FieldUpdater.update()`" method is triggered and performs an UPDATE into database.

Is there a "best practice" to prevent the update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare the old value with the new value, and fire the event only when the values differ

```
column.setFieldUpdater(new FieldUpdater<Row, String>()
{
    public void update(int index, Row row, String value)
    {
        Object oldValue = row.getCellValue(code);

        //if value is different than oldValue 
        //then fire event

    }
});
```